# how does hgearman-client work?

Tags: haskell, gearman

Unfortunately the package [hgearman](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hgearman-0.1.0.2/docs/Network-Gearman-Client.html) does not provide any test or example and I can't work it out for myself how should be combined `connectGearman` and `submitJob` to put a job to the [gearman job server](http://gearman.org/).

The result of `connectGearman` is:

```
ghci> conn <- connectGearman (B.pack "x") ("localhost"::HostName) (4730::Port)
ghci> :t conn
conn :: Either GearmanError GearmanClient
```

but `submitJob` uses private function [`submit`](https://github.com/jperson/hgearman-client/blob/master/Network/Gearman/Client.hs#L63) which deals with `StateT`. So I can only guess the result of `connectGearman` should be wrapped into [`S.StateT GearmanClient IO`](https://github.com/jperson/hgearman-client/blob/master/Network/Gearman/Internal.hs#L27) without faintest idea how to do that.

Comment: I got some help by [haskell beginners mailinglist](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2017-March/017435.html). I'll provide an answer to my own question soon.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/p-alik/hgearman-client/blob/upstream/demos/submit-job.hs) is a submit job example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my implementation of Gearman Client:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Control.Exception (Exception, IOException, catch, throwIO)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Data.Typeable     (Typeable)
import qualified Network.Gearman.Client as C
import Network.Gearman.Internal (Function, GearmanClient, GearmanError, Port, withGearman)
import Network.Socket (HostName)

data ConnectException = ConnectException HostName Port IOException
    deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance Exception ConnectException

main :: IO ()
main = do
  c <- C.connectGearman (B.pack "client-id") host port `catch` \e -> throwIO (ConnectException host port e)
  either (error . B.unpack) return c
    >>= submitFooJob
    >>= either(error . B.unpack) (putStrLn . B.unpack)
  return ()
    where
      host = "localhost"::HostName
      port =  4730::Port
      submitFooJob :: GearmanClient -> IO (Either GearmanError B.ByteString)
      submitFooJob gc = withGearman gc $ C.submitJob (B.pack "foo"::Function) (B.pack "bar")
```