# How does hgearman worker work?

Tags: haskell, gearman

I asked a question [how does hgearman-client work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774191/how-does-hgearman-client-work) three weeks ago. With some help I wrote a simple client application and I'm working on the worker side now. The worker implementation below compiles well and runs without any exception. The only trouble is that `W.runWorker gc (return g)` will not be executed. If I understand it correctly, it's the result of Haskell laziness and `return t` Monad wrapping. But I haven't faintest idea how to get rid of the issue. Could some one help?

```
import qualified Control.Monad.State as S
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Network.Gearman.Client as C
import qualified Network.Gearman.Worker as W
import Network.Gearman.Internal (Function, Port)
import Network.Socket (HostName)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  c <- connect
  case c of
    Left e -> error $ B.unpack e
    Right gc -> do
      (res, _) <- flip S.runStateT gc $ do
        g <- (W.registerWorker name func)
        let t = W.runWorker gc (return g)
        return t >> return ()

      return res
  where
    connect = C.connectGearman (B.pack "i") host port
    host = "localhost"::HostName
    port =  4730::Port
    name = (B.pack "foo")::Function
    func _ = B.pack "bar"
```

Unfortunately an attempt to bind `t <- W.runWorker` ends in compiler exception. If I change the code in this way:

```
Right gc -> do
  (res, _) <- flip S.runStateT gc $ do
    g <- (W.registerWorker name func)
    t <- W.runWorker gc (return ())
    return t >> return  ()

  return res
```

The compilation fails with exception:

```
Couldn't match expected type `S.StateT
                                Network.Gearman.Internal.GearmanClient IO a0'
                with actual type `IO GHC.Conc.Sync.ThreadId'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: t <- W.runWorker gc (return ())
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `do { g <- (W.registerWorker name func);
            t <- W.runWorker gc (return ());
            return t >> return () }'
```

`IO GHC.Conc.Sync.ThreadId` is the result of [runWorker](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hgearman-0.1.0.2/docs/Network-Gearman-Worker.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I implemented a gearman worker in Haskell.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Control.Exception (Exception, IOException, catch, throwIO)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Typeable     (Typeable)
import qualified Network.Gearman.Client as C
import qualified Network.Gearman.Worker as W
import Network.Gearman.Internal (Function, GearmanClient, Port)
import Network.Socket (HostName)
import           Control.Concurrent
import qualified Control.Monad.State as S

data ConnectException = ConnectException HostName Port IOException
    deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance Exception ConnectException

main :: IO ()
main = do
  c <- connect
  gc <- either (error . B.unpack) return c
  work gc
  return ()
  where
    connect = C.connectGearman (B.pack "worker-id") host port `catch` \e -> throwIO (ConnectException host port e)
    host = "localhost"::HostName
    port =  4730::Port

work :: GearmanClient -> IO ()
work gc = do
      (res, _) <- flip S.runStateT gc $ do
          W.registerWorker (B.pack "reverse"::Function)  B.reverse
          S.get >>= (\env -> forever $ S.liftIO (W.runWorker env (return ()) >> threadDelay (1000*1000)))
          return ()
      return res
```

Answer (score 1):

A value of type `Gearman a` for some `a` is an *action*, a recipe to do something.  You can *bind* together such recipes to make bigger recipes, until you have constructed the `main` recipe which is the one that gets run.

Practically speaking, it means if you are running a do-block that looks like this:

```
do ...
   foo
   ...
```

then `foo` will be run.  If you have a do-block that looks like this:

```
do ...
   ret <- foo
   ...
```

then `foo` will be run and the result of running `foo` will be stored in ret.  Those two syntaxes are binds.  However if you are running a do-block that looks like this:

```
do ...
   let ret = foo
   ...
```

then `foo` will not be run -- instead you are just asking for the variable `ret` to be shorthand for `foo`, so `foo` and `ret` are afterwards interchangeable.

So now you can see, in:

```
do g <- W.registerWorker name func
   let t = W.runWorker gc (return g)
   return t >> return ()
```

the second line does not actually *run* a worker, it just lets `t` be a shorthand for running a worker.  Returning an action does not bind it either.  You need to bind:

```
   t <- W.runWorker gc (return g)
```

By the way, I've been looking at the documentation and it looks like `registerWorker` returns a `Gearman ()`, which means that the result of running the action is `()`, or "nothing interesting".  So `g` is nothing interesting, you could get rid of it and say

```
do W.registerWorker name func
   t <- W.runWorker gc (return ())
   return t >> return ()
```

Presumably in place of that `return ()` in the second line you would put an action that you wanted to run in the worker.  Like:

```
   t <- W.runWorker gc $ do
       ... the things you want the worker to do ...
   return t >> return ()
```

And finally that last line: `return t >> return ()`, also written

```
do return t
   return ()
```

is exactly the same thing as `return ()`.  `return x` constructs an action with no side-effects, which is only used for the result.  Then when you use `>>` (or don't bind the result in a `do` block) you run an action only for its side-effects and discard its result.  So the first `return` does nothing whatsoever.

Comment: I'm really appreciate you detailed answer. I tried `t <- W.runWorker gc (return g)` as well. Unfortunately in this case the compiler complains about `Couldn't match expected type`. That's the reason why I turned to let + return; I'll add the code snippet and the exception to my question.